# use 'system' call to execute WGET command in C (linux)

Tags: c, linux, wget

I am learning C and would like to do the following operations on a Linux Machine.

1. Use 'system' call to execute WGET
2. Then the WGET call should download the entire webpage

In my below program I am getting error 'wget is missing url'

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    #define BUFFLEN 2500

    int main()
    {

        system(wget -P ./Folder http://www.google.com)

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: The argument to `wget` must be a string -- put it in quotes.

Comment: I don't see how that program could even have compiled, let alone run and given you the error message you posted. Please post the actual code.

Comment: The program compiled and then I got the error. Otherwise I would never have posted the error. :)

Comment: There's no way the code you posted in the question could possibly have compiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/?kw=system) command takes a const char* parameter. Also, you forgot the semicolon on the line with the system call. The following snippet works perfectly on my machine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("wget -P ./Folder http://www.google.com");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code he posted is obviously not what he actually ran, since it won't even compile without the quotes and semicolon. Perhaps we should wait until he posts something real before trying to answer.

Comment: Also, would the flag `-quiet` be responsible for quiet mode.